# How to use AFNetworking to save cookies permanently forever, until the app is deleted from the iPhone?

Tags: ios, cookies, afnetworking

Can someone please show me how to save cookies FOREVER using AFNetworking for iOS?  I'm using ios7 but I think this should not matter?

The use case is that upon successful authentication with a webservice, it gives me two cookies that I need to pass along with every single request. These cookies never expire, or expire years from now.  As long as I have the cookies with each HTTPS request, the user doesn't have to login again.  I understand that AFNetworking automatically persists cookies until you quit the app, but I need the cookies to last forever until the user deletes the app from their phone.

1) Upon successful authentication, the webservice hands me two cookies.  How do I access them? Do I go straight to NSHTTPCookie storage and grab the cookie by its name, or is there an AFNetworking "way" to do this?

2) How do I save these two magic cookies permanently so that my subclass of AFHTTPClient passes these two magic cookies along  with each request?  Do I just save them inside a keychain or NSUserDefaults or NSURLCredentialsStorage?  Or again is there an AFNetworking way to do this?  I read about a setAuthorization() method inside AFNetworking but I'm not sure if this applies to username/password and cookies as well.

3) How do I delete these cookies the AFNetworking way?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

AFNetworking doesn't do anything explicitly with cookies so there is no "AFNetworking way" of dealing with cookies. You'll work with NSHTTPCookie and NSHTTPCookieStorage.

In my projects I didn't need to do anything specific to the requests to get them to work with cookies. If you need different request behavior than AFNetworking provides by default, you override `requestWithMethod:path:parameters:` in your `AFHTTPClient` subclass.

1. To get the cookies returned from an AFJSONRequest, for example

   ```
   NSURLRequest* request = <some request returned from your AFHTTPClient subclass>
   AFJSONRequestOperation* op = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request 
    success:^(NSURLRequest* request, NSHTTPURLResponse* response, id userData) {
       NSArray* cookies = [NSHTTPCookie cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:[response allHeaderFields] forURL:url];
    }
    failure:...
   ```
2. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570737/shared-instance-of-nshttpcookiestorage-does-not-persist-cookies?rq=1) says to set an expiration date on the cookie. If you want to persist the cookies yourself, you can convert the cookies to a dictionary and save that. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795506/storing-authentication-tokens-on-ios-nsuserdefaults-vs-keychain) says to use the keychain.

   ```
   NSMutableDictionary* cookieDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:cookiePrefs];
   for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in cookies) {
      [cookieDictionary setValue:cookie.properties forKey:cookie.name];
   }
   ```
3. Remove the cookies from the NSHTTPCookieStorage. There is some [trickiness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747012/nshttpcookies-refuse-to-be-deleted/15198874#15198874) to watch out for. If you've saved the cookies yourself, delete the stored values however is appropriate.

   ```
   NSArray* cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookiesForURL:theUrl];
   for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in cookies) {
      [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
   }
   ```