# Storing Cookies in Keychain

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, wkwebview, keychain

My app uses OAuth when logging in. A user is presented with a web view, once they sign in they are given the required tokens, however a cookie is also set. I am using that cookie when opening an `WKWebView` within my app so I can render an authenticated page.

These are not persisted across app restarts however, initially I was storing these on `UserDefaults` depending on the application life cycle change

```
applicationDidBecomeActive

applicationWillEnterForeground

applicationDidEnterBackground

applicationWillTerminate
```

However I do like the idea of storing anything sensitive in here and would much rather store the cookie on the keychain.

What I cannot understand is how I can serialize it in a way that lets me store it?

When I log out a stored cookie, an example I can see is

```
<NSHTTPCookie
    version:0
    name:SOMETHING_SOMETHING
    value:a_random_hash
    expiresDate:'2020-04-20 18:50:49 +0000'
    created:'2019-04-21 18:50:49 +0000'
    sessionOnly:FALSE
    domain:.domain.tld
    partition:none
    sameSite:none
    path:/
    isSecure:TRUE
    isHTTPOnly: YES
 path:"/" isSecure:TRUE isHTTPOnly: YES>)
```

Comment: Why not store cookies in [cookie storage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nshttpcookiestorage)?

Comment: It was my understanding these are not persisted across restarts etc

Comment: They're stored until `expiresDate`.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570737/shared-instance-of-nshttpcookiestorage-does-not-persist-cookies

Comment: hmmm for me they simply do not persist once the application has been closed and re opened if the cookie does not have an expiry date

Comment: possibly duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997601/store-nshttpcookie-in-ios-keychain-using-swift/68826223#68826223
I also have a solution to solve this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68826223/2082851